# Editing the row of tableview(displaying a array of strings) which uses binding causes exception

Tags: objective-c, exception, binding, tableview, nsarraycontroller

I am a newbie in using Bindings. I started developing a sample application which has a table view and arraycontroller. My data is a array of strings.

I am able to display the strings in the array after doing all the necessary binding using interface builder. But when  I try to edit any row of the table view I get the following exception.

I have no idea why this is coming.

I used following code -

.h file

## import

```
interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> 

property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window; 
property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView; 
property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *arrayContents; 

end
```

.m file

```
implementation AppDelegate 

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification { } 

-(id)init 
{ 
   self = [super init] ; 
   if (nil!=self) 
   { 
       _arrayContents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
       [_arrayContents addObject:@"asdasdasd"]; 
       [_arrayContents addObject:@"asdasdasdsasdc"]; 
   } 
   return self; 
}

end
```

Can any one help me in solving this and point out the mistake?
Thnx.

2013-06-26 11:15:56.055 sample[4643:303] Exception detected while handling key input.
2013-06-26 11:15:56.068 sample[4643:303] Error setting value for key path  of object asdasdasdsasdc (from bound object  identifier: (null)): [<__NSCFConstantString 0x100002a18> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .

Comment: put some amount of code.

Comment: .h file 
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
property (nonatomic,strong)  NSMutableArray *arrayContents;
end

.m file 
implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
}
-(id)init
{
self = [super init] ;
if (nil!=self)
{
_arrayContents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [_arrayContents addObject:@"asdasdasd"];
        [_arrayContents addObject:@"asdasdasdsasdc"];
    }
    return self;
}
end

Comment: not as comment add the code in the question by editing it.There is an Edit option there under the question

Comment: post the code used for editing the cell.

Comment: This is all the code I have written to populate the tableview. I have not written any other code. I have not written tableview:setObject:forTableColumn since it will not be called as this application uses binding.